# Remove everything after a string pattern in php

Tags: php

I have a list of patterns: `$allowedTLDS = array(".de", ".at", ".ch", ".org", ".com", ".eu");`

Now I a have string like `30212622mail@myname.com` and I want to cut everything after the .com away to get the plain mail address. 
I've written this function so far:

```
function extract_correct_email_address($string){
    $allowedTLDS = array(".de", ".at", ".ch", ".org", ".com", ".eu");
    $foundMatch = false;
    $foundTLD = "";
    foreach ($allowedTLDS as $tld) {
        if (strpos($string, $tld) !== FALSE) {
            //found a match
            $foundMatch = true;
            $foundTLD = $tld;
            break 1;
        }
    }

    if($foundMatch){
        $str = strtok( $string, $foundTLD).$foundTLD;

        return $str;
    }


    return NULL;
}
```

Now I have for example these addresses where I get the output on the right side:

```
input: info@meq.dewww.meq.de 
output: info@meq.de 
expected: info@meq.de (this one is correct)

input: info@cool-name.de 
output: info@co.de 
expected: info@cool-name.de

input: something-cool123@nice.decool123.nice.de 
expected: something-cool123@nice.de
```

I hope it is understandable what I want to archive. What am I doing something wrong in the function?

Comment: What if someone has the email `rachel.denise@email.com` for example?

Comment: @WillParky93 then it should return the whole mail `rachel.denise@email.com ` because after the .com is nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it with this nice regular expression - you just can add TLDs:

```
function extract_correct_email_address($string){
    // pattern do match email addresses
    $pattern = '/[a-z0-9_\-\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.(de|at|ch|org|com|eu)(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i'; 
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);

    if(count($matches[0])<1) {
        return null;
    }
    return $matches[0];
}


// example string         
$string = 'fdsaf das D hansi@test.dewww.lol.net franz@gibts.atdasf dasf asd';
var_dump(extract_correct_email_address($string));
```

Result:

> string(15) "hansi@test.de"

Of course you can extend this to use for extracting multiple emails. Instead of `matches[0]` check all matches instead.

Comment: yeah it looks much nicer with regex. I'm currently testing it and after the first 10 runs it looks like it works perfect! Thanks for that.

Comment: With `preg_match_all` you can also extend it easily to match multiple email addresses, just in case you may need this once.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. I'm only inspecting the part after the "@". There could be the case somebody ist named "miller.denis@bla.com", so that .de would also be parsed

```
public function parseMail(){
    $string = "something-cool123@nice.decool123.nice.de";
    $allowedTLDS = array(".de", ".at", ".ch", ".org", ".com", ".eu");
    $mail = explode("@", $string);
    foreach ($allowedTLDS as $tld) {
        if (strpos($mail[1], $tld) !== FALSE) {
            //found a match
            $foundTLD = $tld;
            dump($mail[1]);
            $str = strtok($mail[1], $foundTLD);
            return $mail[0].'@'.$str.$foundTLD;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using regexp instead:

```
preg_replace('/(\.(de|at|ch|org|com|eu)).*$/', '\1', $email);
```

Just add your `$allowedTLDS` inside the parenthesis.

#### Examples

```
$ php -r "echo preg_replace('/(\.(de|at|ch|org|com|eu)).*$/', '\1', 'info@meq.dewww.meq.de') . PHP_EOL;"
> info@meq.de
$ php -r "echo preg_replace('/(\.(de|at|ch|org|com|eu)).*$/', '\1', 'info@cool-name.de') . PHP_EOL;"
> info@cool-name.de
$ php -r "echo preg_replace('/(\.(de|at|ch|org|com|eu)).*$/', '\1', 'something-cool123@nice.decool123.nice.de ') . PHP_EOL;"
> something-cool123@nice.de
```